# How to install libpng-dev on Mac

Tags: r, macos, png, libpng, reticulate

I am trying to install the [`reticulate`](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/reticulate/index.html) package on my Mac and it depends on the [`png`](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/png/index.html) package, which in turn depends on `libpng`. I installed `libpng` with [brew](https://brew.sh/) but the `png` package fails due to a missing `libpng-config`:

```
/bin/sh: libpng-config: command not found
```

However I have this in `/opt/homebrew/bin/libpng-config`:

```
which libpng-config
/opt/homebrew/bin/libpng-config
```

I [found this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/package-installation-failure/28938) that specifies the need for `libpng-dev` but I have no idea how to install that on my Mac. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I tried with the following error: Installing package into ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.1/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in contrib.url(repos, type) : 
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: install.packages -> startsWith -> contrib.url
Execution halted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processes not started from a shell may not inherit environment variables from that shell. Start R in Terminal to make sure that your R process inherits `PATH` from the Terminal shell where you have run `which`. Something like

```sh
$ Rscript -e "install.packages(\"png\")"
```

should work, though you may need to select a CRAN mirror, in which case the above will throw an error. You can do that in the `install.packages` call, like so:

```sh
$ Rscript -e "install.packages(\"png\", repos = \"https://cloud.r-project.org\")"
```

or by setting a global option, like so:

```sh
$ Rscript -e "options(repos = \"https://cloud.r-project.org\"); install.packages(\"png\")"
```

For details, see the R for macOS [FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#I-get-_0060_0060command-not-found_0027_0027-in-the-GUI-yet-it-works-in-the-Terminal-_002d_002d-why_003f) and `?options`.